# Klaxon's JSON pretty printing outputs "["result"]"

Tags: json, kotlin, klaxon

```
val time = json.lookup<String?>("query.results.channel.title").toJsonString(true)
```

outputs

> ["Yahoo! Weather - Nome,AK,US"]

is there a way to get the output without the brackets and the quotation marks ?

I guess that

```
.replace("[\"","").replace("\"]","")
```

isn't the best way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brackets are contained in the default implementation (see https://github.com/cbeust/klaxon/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/com/beust/klaxon/DSL.kt at the very bottom function `appendJsonStringImpl`)

So it is not possible, to remove them by configuration.

It might work if you write an extension function for this particular class, but i guess this is not what you want.

So this is currently not possible without writing your own extension(-function).